# Submenu da mesma largura do menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

O submenu fica do tamanho do texto, gostaria que ele ficasse do tamanho do menu

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow:  0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
header > nav {
    position: relative;
}
header nav * {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
header > nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header > nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
header > nav > ul > li {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
header > nav > ul > li[ng-click]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: none;
}
header > nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header><nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Usuários
            <ul>
                <li>Conectar</li>
                <li>Cadastrar</li>
                <li>Meu perfil</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>UFEF</li>
    </ul>
</nav></header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa definir uma `position: relative` na `ul` de primeiro nível para que o `position: absolute` da `ul` de segundo nível se baseie no elemento onde ele é filho, e então colocar um `width: 100%`.

Ficaria assim:

```css
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow:  0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
header > nav {
    position: relative;
}
header nav * {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
header > nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header > nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
   position: relative; /* adicionado */
}
header > nav > ul > li {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
header > nav > ul > li[ng-click]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
header > nav > ul > li > ul {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%; /* adicionado */
    transition: all .7s ease; /* adicionado */
    height: 0; /* adicionado */
    opacity: 0; /* adicionado */
}

/* adicionado */
header > nav > ul > li > ul:hover {
    height: 150px; /* 3x line-height das LIs */
    opacity: 1; /* adicionado */
}

header > nav > ul > li > ul > li {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    /* padding-left: 15px;  removido */
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}
header > nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header><nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Usuários
            <ul>
                <li>Conectar</li>
                <li>Cadastrar</li>
                <li>Meu perfil</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>UFEF</li>
    </ul>
</nav></header>
```

Mas para se precaver desses problemas com `position`, você pode definir todos os elementos com `position: relative`. Coloque no INÍCIO do seu CSS:

```
<style>
*{
   position: relative;
}
...
</style>
```

Comment: Funciona, mas sabe como posso fazer isso com flex em vez de width?

Comment: Cara, só conheço com `width` mesmo. Veja um menu parecido que tb usa width no flexbox: https://codepen.io/barkins/pen/KzrKrj

Comment: Sim, atualizei a resposta com o efeito.

Comment: Adicionei um efeito de opacidade para ficar mais suave ainda :D

Comment: Fico top valeu!